# Escaping quotes PHP echo

Tags: php, escaping, echo

I'm having some weird problem escaping " in an echo function.

```
        echo "<a href=\"" + "$site" +  "target=\"_blank\">Site</a>";
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing weird, it's how you're trying to join strings together using a `+` sign rather than dots.

Comment: or just write it out like this `echo "<a href=\"$site\"target=\"_blank\">Site</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the javascript way for one. Concatenating in PHP works using **.** or **,**.
Then you are using to many "

Try this line:

```
echo "<a href=\"".$site." target=\"_blank\">Site</a>";
```

Comment: solved, thank you! (New to php...)